# Split strings on whitespaces, but do not remove them

Tags: python, string

I want to split strings based on whitespace and punctuation, but the whitespace and punctuation should still be in the result.

For example:

```
Input: text = "This is a text; this is another   text.,."
Output: ['This', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'text', '; ', 'this', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'another', '   ', 'text', '.,.']
```

Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
def classify(b):
    """
    Classify a character.
    """
    separators = string.whitespace + string.punctuation
    if (b in separators):
        return "separator"
    else:
        return "letter"

def tokenize(text):
    """
    Split strings to words, but do not remove white space.
    The input must be of type str, not bytes
    """
    if (len(text) == 0):
        return []

    current_word = "" + text[0]
    previous_mode = classify(text)
    offset = 1
    results = []
    while offset < len(text):
        current_mode = classify(text[offset]) 
        if  current_mode == previous_mode:
            current_word += text[offset]
        else:
            results.append(current_word)
            current_word = text[offset]
            previous_mode = current_mode
        offset += 1

    results.append(current_word)
    return results
```

It works, but it's so C-style. Is there a better way in Python?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: this one is slightly more involved as it splits on more than just whitespace. But at the same time it is just a variation, and I had totally forgot about that answer. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
import re
re.split('([\s.,;()]+)', text)
```

This splits on arbitrary-width whitespace (including tabs and newlines) plus a selection of punctuation characters, and by grouping the split text you tell `re.sub()` to include it in the output:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "This is a text; this is another   text.,."
>>> re.split('([\s.,;()]+)', text)
['This', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'text', '; ', 'this', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'another', '   ', 'text', '.,.', '']
```

If you only wanted to match spaces (and not other whitespace), replace `\s` with a space:

```
>>> re.split('([ .,;()]+)', text)
['This', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'text', '; ', 'this', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'another', '   ', 'text', '.,.', '']
```

Note the extra trailing empty string; a split always has a head and a tail, so text starting or ending in a split group will always have an extra empty string at the start or end. This is easily removed.

Comment: If you split with `\w+` that will also have same effect.I believe empty string at begining.

Comment: @AruneshSingh: yup, because then the string starts with a split group.

Comment: Thanks. Regex is surely powerful, I must learn that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I freaking love you man